# Using Autohotkey, is there a way to bring up clipboard manager clippings (like CLCL)

Tags: autohotkey

My company has pushed a horrible app that has a default hotkey of ^!c, with no way to change it or to kill the app. This is my favorite key combo for my clipboard manager :) I have managed to block the app coming up with autohotkey, but ideally I would like to have it bring up my clipboard manager like it always has. I have tried several things. Autohotkey remapping ^!c to a different hotkey for the app doesn't seem to work, and just launching the clipboard manager exe doesn't work on any I've tried.

Is there a way to send a command to any clipboard managers aside from its hotkey? Am I correct in that remapping the key doesn't work, or is there some way around this?

If I map my clipboard manager to !F2, this doesn't bring it up, it just blocks the offending app:

```
^!c::!F2
```

Comment: Please provide some more background information

Comment: What do you mean "it just *blocks*" the offending app?  What blocks it?

Comment: Can you change the shortcut in your clipboard manager?

Answer (score 0):

This AutoHotkey script should achieve what you're looking for.

The idea is this: currently win+r opens the Run dialog, I want win+r to open/activate Notepad instead,
and to assign an alternative hotkey for the Run dialog.

To interact with rather than open the clipboard manager, should most probably require
the use of `PostMessage/SendMessage` or `ControlSend`, and `DetectHiddenWindows, On`.

Note: if you were able to change the shortcut key on your clipboard manager to a shortcut key you never use, perhaps <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+D</kbd>, then `SendInput ^!d` would trigger the program.

So you would change the hotkeys and edit/replace the Notepad lines below, to suit your requirements.

```
;tested on Windows 7

#r::
IfWinExist, ahk_class Notepad
WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad
else
Run, "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
Return

^#r::
SendInput #r
Return
```